# Returning Address of Max Cell in Vba

Tags: excel, vba

Don't know much about Excel vba. How can I return the *location* of the cell in the range that is the maximum value (e.g., "MaxVal")?

```
  Sub FillSched()


    Dim LTrig As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MaxVal As Double
    Dim WorkRange As Range


    Worksheets("Inputs").Activate
    LTrig = Range("Trigger").Value

    Worksheets("Daily").Activate

    For i = 0 To 5
        If Range("AggInvStart").Offset(i, 0).Value > LTrig Then
        Set WorkRange = Range("M" & i + 5 & ":" & "O" & i + 5)
        MaxVal = WorksheetFunction.Max(WorkRange)
        End If    
    Next i


End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code MaxValue is just a calculated value not a range.
You would need to get the position of the WorkRange that contains that MaxValue

```
  Sub FillSched()


    Dim LTrig As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MaxVal As Double
    Dim WorkRange As Range
    Dim col Long
    Dim rw As Long

    Worksheets("Inputs").Activate
    LTrig = Range("Trigger").Value

    Worksheets("Daily").Activate

    For i = 0 To 5
        If Range("AggInvStart").Offset(i, 0).Value > LTrig Then
        Set WorkRange = Range("M" & i + 5 & ":" & "O" & i + 5)
        MaxVal = WorksheetFunction.Max(WorkRange)
        rw = WorkRange.Row
        col = WorkRange.Column
        End If
    Next i

MsgBox "MaxValue is in Row: " & rw & ", Column: " & col

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FillSched()

  Dim rngSearch As Range, WorkRange As Range
  Dim MaxVal as Double, lCol as Long, lRow as Long, sAddress as String

  With WorksheetFunction
    Set rngSearch = Range("AggInvStart").Resize(6, 1)      ' Define search range
    MaxVal = .Max(rngSearch.Value2)                        ' Get its max value
    If MaxVal <= Range("Trigger").Value2 Then _ ' Use this if you do not want to
      Exit Sub                           ' find MaxVal when is <= Range("Trigger")
    lCol = Range("AggInvStart")(1,1).Column                ' Get first column
    lRow = Range("AggInvStart")(1,1).Row - 1               ' Get one row before first
    Set WorkRange = Cells(lRow + .Match(MaxVal, rngSearch, 0), lCol) ' Get its location
    sAddress = WorkRange.Address                           ' Get Cell Address
    lRow = WorkRange.Row                                   ' Get Row No
    lCol = WorkRange.Column                                ' Get Column No
  End With

End Sub
```

I hope this helps!

PS: I think that in your original code, you want `LTrig` to be `Double`. Also, it has to be initialized to a very small number (the code as it stands will fail if the `max` value is negative because the `Dim` statement initializes `LTrig` to zero.)